# angularjs ng-include manage dom from the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there a way to manage the dom using ng-include
(for instance show the p with color:red)
I've tried with

```
<body>
      <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
           <div ng-include="'my.html'"></div>
      </div>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            var app = angular.module("myTest", []);
            app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
                $scope.$on('$includeContentRequested',function(event,data){console.log(event.targetScope);});
            });

    </script>
    </body>

//my.html
<p>Hello</p>
```

but in the event object I don't find any handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ng-include has access to the parent scope and can use binding expression using `ng-style` and `ng-class`. So for example if you ng-include contains

```
<p ng-style="{color:propname}"></p>
```

From the controller you can do

```
 app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){
              $scope.propname=red;
            });
```

Comment: so there is no way to get access to the dom of the included file, is it ?

Comment: You can access DOM using regular css selector, but there should be no reason to access it and such access should be wrapped inside a directive